# Having trouble with widespread faucet

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

Faucet was leaking from right/cold side, so I tried to remove the handle to replace catridge. After unscrewing the small handle Allen screw and pulling, I think the handle came off with part of the cartridge. Tried separating the two with wd-40/vinegar + pliers and that didn't work.

The bottom of the fixture is blocked by the L-shaped outlet to the faucet and the top is blocked by the square decorative piece. I've tried gripping the two parts and turning counter-clockwise but that hasn't worked. There's also no company/model markings. My bathtub faucet asys American Standard, but looking at American Standard faucets online they don't have the L shaped attachment on the bottom.

Does anyone happen to know the company/model of this faucet?

[image: Img 1]

[image: Img 2]

[image: Img 3]

[image: Img 4]

Answer (score 3):

For posterity:

Used a wrench to remove the square framing,

Soaked both ends of the broken cartridge in CLR and that helped make the moving parts move again. (Still required some effort)

Used the following video and website to narrow down the Company that made the cartridge, and ordered a new one!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odHoTMmbscg
[www.faucetpartsplus.com](http://www.faucetpartsplus.com)